# Hyperledger Fabric chain code install using connection profile

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I don't want to install chain code on multiple peers by going into them individually. can i use connection profile option and provide all peer connection address so that i can install chain code on all the peers at the same time or is there any other method available to do so..?

How to use this option in Hyperleadger-fabric...?

`$ peer chaincode install --connectionProfile`

I've tried creating connection.json with following

```
"peers": {
    "peer0.org1.example.com": {
        "url": "grpc://peer0.org1.example.com:7051"
    },
    "peer1.org1.example.com": {
        "url": "grpc://peer1.org1.example.com:7051"
    },
    "peer0.org2.example.com": {
        "url": "grpc://peer0.org2.example.com:7051"
    },
}
```

and passed this file to connection Profile

```
$ peer chaincode install --connectionProfile connection.json -n test -l node -v 1.0 -p /path_to_chaincode
```

but this installed chaincode only on the default peer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--connectionProfile` should actually only be associated / available for `peer chaincode invoke` and `peer chaincode query`.  It was not intended to be used by `peer chaincode install`.

Also, installing chaincode requires you to be an admin for the peer, so it's unlikely that any admin will be able to install chaincode on peers from other organizations.

It's probably not a bad idea to enable support for installing on multiple peers in your same org assuming you use the same admin for all of an org's peers.

Comment: Thanks Gari for the prompt reply. Was just wondering how do we push the upgrade chaincode to all the peers then..?. and how do we make sure that all the peers are using upgraded chaincode.

Comment: It's pretty easy to write either a script which just loops through a list of peers and calls the CLI individually or better yet use one of the SDKs to build a simply deployment tool.
If peers do not have the proper version of the chaincode installed, then they will not be able to launch the chaincode when they receive the upgrade transaction.
Once it is installed, the next time someone tries to invoke it will be launched